# regex to find a specific word inside a curly bracket

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to come up with an regex expression to extract all of the words inside a double curly bracket.

```
{{ 'apple' | translate }}
{{'orange' | translate}}
{{'banana' | translate}}
```

result should be

apple, orange, banana

any help is appreciated.

Comment: [`{{\s*('|")(.*?)\1`](https://www.regex101.com/r/FK38V5/1) Extract second captured group.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What's the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following regex:

```
{{.*?(['"])(.*?)\1.*?}}
```

It assumes that you are using either `'` or `"` as the notations for your strings.

Here is a small example of it in action:

```js
let string = `
  {{ 'apple' | translate }}
  {{'orange' | translate}}
  {{'banana' | translate}}
`;

let words = [];
string.replace(/{{.*?(['"])(.*?)\1.*?}}/g, (...args) => words.push(args[2]));

console.log(words);
```

[Usage in Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/q9ySje/1)